doubt about proof in folland book
I am having  hard time to understand a roof in  the book

$1$ what does it mean to be a Borel measure on $S^{n-1}$?
$2$ how does he obtained $=\rho \times \sigma((a, b] \times E) \text {. }$?

Borel measures are defined on any topological space. $S^{n-1}$ is given its usual topology. $d\rho (r)=r^{n-1}dr$. Apply definition of product measure.
